# Why can't I use this code to select the max row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to select the row that contains the largest number and have accomplished it using this fairly simple query:

```
SELECT s1.score, name
FROM scores s1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(score) score
    FROM scores
    GROUP BY id
) s2 ON s1.score = s2.score
```

All it does (If im not wrong), is just checking if the `score` field is equal the the `MAX(score)`. So why can't we just do it using one single `SELECT` statement ?. Something like this:

```
SELECT id, score
FROM scores
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(score) = score
```

*The code above does not work, I want to ask why it is not working, because its essentially doing the same thing as the previous code I posted

Also here's the data I'm working with:

[image: Data]

Comment: Is `MAX(score)` guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause uses the aggregated values, it no longer has access to individual rows.

Comment: If im not wrong - you are wrong sub query works out max score per id which is not necessarily the same as the max over the whole dataset. the join on score will not return the max per id or the max per dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your second query is the fact that the `GROUP BY` clause requires all non-aggregated fields within its context. In your case you are dealing with three fields (namely "*id*", "*score*" and "*MAX(score)*") and you're referencing only one (namely "*id*") inside the `GROUP BY` clause.

Fixing that would require you to add the non-aggregated "*score*" field inside your `GROUP BY` clause, as follows:

```
SELECT id, score
FROM scores
GROUP BY id, score
HAVING MAX(score) = score
```

Though this would lead to a wrong aggregation and output, because it would attempt to get the maximum score for each combination of (id, score).

And if you'd attempt to remove the "*score*" field from both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, to solve the non-aggregated columns issue, as follows:

```
SELECT id
FROM scores
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(score) = score
```

Then the `HAVING` clause would complain as long it references the "*score*" field but it is found neither within the `SELECT` clause nor within the `GROUP BY` clause.

There's really no way for you to use that kind of notation, as it either violates the full `GROUP_BY` mode, or it just returns the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

It returns all persons with same score which the score is the max:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY score desc) RN
FROM scores
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your queries return

```
DROP table if exists t;

create table t
(id int,score int);

insert into t values
(1,10),(2,20),(3,20);

SELECT s1.id,s1.score
FROM t s1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(score) score
    FROM t
    GROUP BY id
) s2 ON s1.score = s2.score ;

+------+-------+
| id   | score |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    10 |
|    2 |    20 |
|    2 |    20 |
|    3 |    20 |
|    3 |    20 |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

SELECT id, score,max(score)
FROM t
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(score) = score

+------+-------+------------+
| id   | score | max(score) |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 |    10 |         10 |
|    2 |    20 |         20 |
|    3 |    20 |         20 |
+------+-------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Neither result seems to be what you are looking for. You could clarify by posting sample data and desired outcome.